# DocuSign Powerform: how to set different custom URL for each Powerform?

Tags: docusignapi

I currently have 2 Powerforms and 2 Brands. I tried to set different redirect URL for each Powerform through "Bands > destination URLs > Signing Completed" (I already chose the brand for each template). Unfortunately, it didnt work.

It only works if I set the URL in "signing settings > in-session landing pages -> Signing Completed", however it will apply to all the Powerforms wiht the same URL.

Comment: Are you using Email Powerform or a direct powerform, if you want to use Brands then I would suggest you to use email Powerform.

Comment: What is Email Powerform? the one Im using is embedding an iframe with powerform URL in HTML @AmitKBist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Powerform there is an option to check Require Email Validation. Whiche means that Signer must verify their identity through email before accessing and signing the PowerForm. Recipient provides email address and then receives a validation code for the PowerForm. Recipient must retrieve the code and provide it in order to sign.

Please check https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-create-a-powerform to see how to create an email powerform

So if you make an Email Powerform then it uses Brand and your Brand's Destination URL will be called. But when you use Direct Powerform then  in-session landing pages will be called.

Comment: As I said I really want to keep the whole interaction within the messenger channel not switching to email all of a sudden

Answer (score 0):

My bad, answered the wrong question... This might be relevant though so i'll leave it here.
My question was: [DocuSign: Is it possible to send a custom payload via PowerForm link and get it back via webhook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766702/docusign-is-it-possible-to-send-a-custom-payload-via-powerform-link-and-get-it)

So according to this documentation: https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-populate-custom-document-fields-in-a-web-powerform

You can set various fields. My mistake was  that I was trying to set custom fields of the template - which have to be added to the document at some point and are visible.

The solution is simple - set an envelope custom field which are dynamic and can be created on the fly.